# Функция watch выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp

```
const { src, dest, watch } = require('gulp');

function watching() {
    watch(['app/scss/style.scss', styles])
    watch(['app/js/main.js', scripts])
}

exports.watching = watching;

$ gulp watching
[12:49:20] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\gulpfile.js
[12:49:20] Starting 'watching'...
[12:49:20] 'watching' errored after 2.44 ms
[12:49:20] TypeError: expected a string
    at module.exports (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\is-negated-glob\index.js:5:11)
    at sortGlobs (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\glob-watcher\index.js:67:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at watch (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\glob-watcher\index.js:64:18)
    at Gulp.watch (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\gulp\index.js:48:10)
    at watching (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\gulpfile.js:23:5)
    at taskWrapper (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (node:domain:433:15)
    at runBound (node:domain:444:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\Users\dknic\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\gulp-start\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
```

Comment: Текст ошибки *"expected a string"* вам о чем-нибудь говорит?